# How to append a select result columns to anther select result in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the sample select 1:

```
SELECT A, B FROM Table1
```

And here is the second one:

```
SELECT C, D FROM Table2
```

The record quantity of select 1 and select 2 is the same and the result should be something like:

```
A, B, C, D
```

Ok, I provided some data results:

Result 1:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
+---+---+
```

Result 2:

```
+---+----+
| C | D  |
+---+----+
| 4 |  8 |
| 5 |  9 |
| 6 | 10 |
+---+----+
```

And final result should be:

```
+---+---+----+----+
| A | B | C  | D  |
+---+---+----+----+
| 1 | 2 |  4 |  8 |
| 3 | 4 |  5 |  9 |
| 5 | 6 |  6 |  10|
+---+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server

Comment: Does each query return just one row? If not, could you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get please?

Comment: @Mureinik
The row count of both results are the same.

Comment: @Ali so how do you decide which rows in each result match? Just by their order?

Comment: @Mureinik
I know this looks ridiculous but they don't have anything in common, their row count is always the same and I need to combine them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea: use a unique key where you can join on, e.g. the row number / rank. Here is a working example: ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fe1a/3))

```
set @rank1 := 0;
set @rank2 := 0;
select a, b, c, d
from
  (select @rank1 := @rank1 + 1 AS rank, a, b from table1) t1 inner join
  (select @rank2 := @rank2 + 1 AS rank, c, d from table2) t2 on t2.rank = t1.rank
order by t1.rank
```

Comment: Brilliant! I do like it!